# Cannot determine determinant

Tags: matrices

so i have two $3x3$ matrices. The first and third column of each matrix have the elements $a,b,c$ and $d,e,f$. In the middle column of the first matrix the elements are $1,2,3$ and in the middle column of the second matrix the elements are $3,5,7$. The determinant of the first matrix is $1$. What is the determinant of the second matrix?

Matrix $A$ is: 
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&1&d\\
b&2&f\\
c&3&f
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix $B$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&3&d\\
b&5&f\\
c&7&f
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\det A=1 \qquad \det B =?
$$

Comment: What have you tried? At the very least you must've tried to expand the two determinants using the regular formula before you got so stuck that you decided to come here, right?

Comment: Your question is somewhat hard to parse, and would likely generate more positive responses if it were properly formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) we obtain
$$
1=\det(A)=- 3ae + 2af + 3bd - bf - 2cd + ce,
$$
and
$$
\det(B)=- 7ae + 5af + 7bd - 3bf - 5cd + 3ce.
$$
Now substitute one of the variables from the first equation (a case distinction is necessary, not to divide by zero), and substitute it in the second equation.
For example, if $3e-2f\neq 0$, we can substitute $a$ from the first equation, and then
$$\det(B)=\frac{bdf - 2bef + bf^2 - cde + 2ce^2 - cef + 7e - 5f}{3e - 2f}$$

Comment: How is that result better than the raw expansion of $\det B$? Just in the numerator you have more terms and of higher degree than the plain expansion has,

Comment: The raw expansion of $\det(B)$ alone does *not* take into account the information of the first equation. We cannot chose the variables arbitrarily, it must satisfy $\det(A)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information to find $\det B$. For example, one case that satisfies your specification is
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
where $\det B=2$, but for
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 & 7 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
we instead have $\det B = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that the determinant is a multilinear function of the columns of the matrix you can see that:

$$
\Delta=\det \begin{bmatrix}
a&3&d\\
b&5&f\\
c&7&f
\end{bmatrix}=
2 \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a&1&d\\
b&2&f\\
c&3&f
\end{bmatrix}
+\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a&1&d\\
b&1&f\\
c&1&f
\end{bmatrix}
=
2-ae+af+bd-bf-cd+ce
$$